# Resource Limit Is Reached - как победить?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, limit, ssi

После внедрения на сайт технологии ssi стала появляться 508 ошибка в браузере - Resource Limit Is Reached. The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

Хостер говорит о какой-то большой нагрузке на процессор.
Даже 2-3 (!) человека на сайте, одновременно просматривающие страницы, которые формируются из ssi, якобы вызывают значительную нагрузку на процессор.

В логах вижу вот такие строки:

2019/03/05 23:59:52 [error] 1184936#1184936: *43041197 subrequests cycle while processing "/css/telefoniya.html" while sending to client, client: 31.130.71.229, server: ля-ля-ля.ru, request: "GET /css/print.css HTTP/2.0", subrequest: "/css/counters.html", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/counters.html", host: "ля-ля-ля.ru", referrer: "[https://ля-ля-ля.ru/infosn.html](https://%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D1%8F.ru/infosn.html)"

Файлы telefoniya.html и counters.html - это как раз ssi вставки.

В первом - скрипт онлайн телефонии который никаких ошибок не вызывал будучи просто частью статичного хтмл-кода.

counters.html - это, соответственно, код счетчиков, установленных на сайт.

Код страницы просто "разбит" на такие блоки: статичные - общие для всех страниц сайта.

Подскажите, неужели ssi - это такая ресурсоемкая технология? Я читала, что она "легче", чем php.

Есть ли способ "победить" эту 508 ошибку?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

**Проблема была как раз в большом количестве этих ssi.**

Я объединила 4 из них, идущие подряд, в один. И проблема решилась.
И страницы стали загружаться очень быстро, и ошибка, тьфу-тьфу, пропала.

Страницы открываются, как минимум, так же быстро, как и написанные на хтмл статичные файлы. Или даже быстрее, по субъективным оценкам.